# Select options not aligning under select element

Tags: html, css, select, offset, select-options

I have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 <div style="width:501px;background:#EEE;">
  <div style="width:100%;max-width:400px;margin:auto;background:#DDD;">
   <select style="width:200px;box-sizing:border-box;">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As the container is set to an uneven number and the select's parent div is set to margin auto, it has trouble aligning it. The result is that the option list is not correctly aligned under select.
This happens in FF 88.01, but not in Edge 93: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbuuR.png)

I can solve it by either setting the select to 199px or the container 500px, but is there another solution that doesn't involve sacrificing the width?

Edit: This happens even without all the containers. Even when I put select on 100% width, by itself on an empty page. It will be a Firefox thing, not my code. Depending on the view port, it's sometimes misaligned, sometimes not.

**Note:** I saw the error in jsfiddle, but running the snippet here does NOT reproduce the issue, regardless of view port. Guess I'll just live with it. I can't change it - odd browser behaviour.

```js
$('#msg').text($(window).width());
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#msg').text($(window).width());
});
```

```css
select{width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test2</option>
</select>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Trying to mush inline CSS with the style tag is not helpful and can be making problems. If this is a unique item, give it a CSS id name. Then you can mess with its position:

html holds the element (item)

```
<div id="panda">
```

css shows how to make it look

```
#panda { width: 100%; background: red }
```

Think of HTML as the architecture of a house; the CSS is the paint and decorative aspects.

2. One thing I am also noticing is that your are using out of date sizing information [pixels] which may not be a help. The demand for a set pixel width [max-width:400px] and "100%" may not be compatible. Any time you can use % or em for size, that is an accurate measurement to scale for all display screen you are using. Please look into % size and em size and see the RWD article and viewport article that follows:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

This will give you the underlying concept. Pixels [fixed size] really stink and can be very hard to do what you want. Think of them as being cast in concrete, they can break the flow of your CSS.I avoid them unless it is very, very necessary [sometimes image height that will be consistent regardless of the device - it can be the same height viewed on a smartphone, tablet, or laptop.] Almost every time you want to say *pixels schmixels* -- the 90s are over -- use a flexible system like % or em. Be aware of the max size of your image / resolution [tiny file will look terrible if you tell it to fill the screen.]

3. One way to figure out where your stuff is related to in the flow is to break the design with a highlighter color so you can see where the things are fitting together in the puzzle. Give an element or page section a red or bright color background or border -- if you can use color to see where the edges of things are and load the page in a browser and this often makes the problem pop up for you. Then you can fix it and take the highlighter color out of the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your extended reply - appreciate it. The reason for the inline styles is because it's just for test, it's nice and short to type out, rather than going back and forth between html file and css file. Unfortunately, for this project I have to use pixels, as the ads are a certain width in px plus it's an old website which mainly works with pixels anyway, but I definitely understand your point.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting! I never used inline to test a style change. I am used to having a few tabs open in Komodo. ^_^ If I am very uncertain if a change will break the heck out of a style, I will use saved copies to bash and see what the output is like.

For older / legacy sites, there will probably all come a turning point where they age out and do not work well since most of the web is running on mobile. I cringe when I find one. I always try and see if people are willing to migrate to a more contemporary design. ^_^

Comment: Haha yeah, this is a responsive website though - it simply uses CSS media queries. The problem does not exist on mobile (plus, selects are treated differently on mobile anyway). But for the desktop fixed size ads are displayed which forces me to work with pixels.

Comment: Yeah ads and banner ads can really suck :( sorry did not know you had that many complex parts moving so the question seems to understate everything going on, looked more like basic problem. Maybe get some Bootstrap code for the benefits of the column system? Is the CSS @media queries via Bootstrap? That is the only idea I have atm.

Comment: Nah, it's okay. I created a simple html test file (as per post, with no css or divs at all - purely body and a select element in it) and it happens there too, and again only on certain screen widths. So, it's not an issue in my code, but a glitch in Firefox. Though it annoys me, I'll leave it.

Comment: If I had a dollar for the render variations between Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, I would be so loaded. I have found Tab keyboard navigation variations for people with disabilities between the Chrome and Firefox. ░ What about the old browser version implementation in CSS like had to do for the various crap versions of if: Internet Explorer 6 &etc - -moz-margin styling -- maybe have JS/JQ if Firefox detected -- then make adjustment to placement like when back in the day there had to be browser detection for the various IE versions that all broke differently. Could that work?

Comment: OK added idea for @-moz- above because comments section gets annoyed if you try to paste code here ^^'  StackOverflow so toucchhyyy - ^^'

Comment: Hi Shellie, adding/removing margins won't do anything. It's the native select options dropdown that's misaligned with the select itself. It's ok. 92% of the visitors are on mobile & tablet anyway, 8% desktop and of those it will be a few who are on Firefox, as most people are on Chrome nowadays. I moved on from it. :) Really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

anchor tag example for Firefox only -- apply to needed element --

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    a {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```